# error when requesting an api made in fastapi

Tags: python, typescript, next.js, fastapi

I am making a login in next js and I make a request to an api that is made in fastapi to return me a cookie the error occurs when I do the fetch in the front-end exactly when I put credentials: 'include' I have done the process only with html and javascript and I save the cookie but when I do it in next.js I get the error

```ts
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

FastAPI

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Response, status
from config.db import conn
from models.user import users
from schemas.user import User
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import datetime
from starlette.status import HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT
from funcions.funcions_jwt import validate_jwt, write_jwt
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import http.cookies as Cookie

key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

user = APIRouter()

@user.post("/login", tags=["users"], status_code=200)
async def login(response: Response, user: User):
    print(user)
    response.set_cookie(key="my_cookie", value=write_jwt(dict(user)), httponly=True)
    return {"message": "Ok"}
```

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from routes.user import user
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import http.cookies as Cookie
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI(
        title="Campesinos API",
        description="API with FastAPI",
        version="0.0.1",
        openapi_tags=[{
            "name": "users",
            "description": "Operations with users"
        }]
)

origins = [
    "*",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["Content-Type"],
)


load_dotenv()

app.include_router(user)
```

Next JS

```ts
import { LoginModel } from "../models";

export const login = (credencials: LoginModel) => {
    console.log('credencials', credencials);
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login';
    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credencials),
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log('res');
        return res.json()
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot allow credentials when `allow_origins = ['*']` as per the [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/). So, the working code snippet for adding CORS middleware would be as follows:

```
origins = [
    "*",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["Content-Type"],
)
```

I have removed `allow_credentials=True` here. You can also modify it to allow credentials by specifying the allowed origins like:

```
origins = [
    "http://localhost:5000/",
    # allowed origins
]
```

Some additional suggestions:

1. Specifying to allow [**Content Type** header](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/#use-corsmiddleware) is not needed.
2. I would suggest you to load origins from [environment variables](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/).

Comment: Thanks I solved it by specifying the url in the CORS but now it doesn't save the cookie in next.js